# ServerMiddleware Error: Unexpected token '&&='

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

The following line in my Nuxt server middleware throws a syntax error:

```js
query._id &&= new mongo.ObjectId(query._id)
```

```
ERROR  ServerMiddleware Error: Unexpected token '&&='

query._id &&= new _mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(query._id);
^^^
```

As far as I know the [logical AND assignment operator (&&=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment) is valid Javascript syntax. If I rewrite this line to

```js
query._id = query._id && new mongo.ObjectId(query._id)
```

it works.

Comment: What version of Node/Deno is it running on. `&&=` is fairly recent and sounds like it's not supported on whichever version of whatever environment it's running in.

Comment: Yes it was a version problem. Do you have a source for me where I can look up these kind of features with their required version?

Comment: Just check the [docs over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment). It's pretty good at showing what versions a feature is available on. Also check out [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=logical%20and%20assignment)

Comment: Lol gotta admit I always glance over that browser support table and have never once noticed that Node is listed there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of operator is only available in Node v15+ versions as told here: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/the-difference-between-and-operators-in-javascript-nodejs-3696b0ce02ff

Because yeah, the new things usually take a bit more time to come to the backend than the front-end.

You're probably running on the latest LTS aka v14, type `node -v` to be sure.

Comment: Oh I didn't think this would be something new, seemed like a basic operator to me like `+=` etc.. I haven't found a comprehensive source that lists these kind of features on a version basis yet.

Comment: For that, you need to look for the official node.js release notes. And this one was late to the party in the JS world. @dado

Comment: JavaScript docs at Mozilla Developer Network [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) includes platform availability. Also check out [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)